# Should {package-writing} and {documentclass-writing} be merged into a new {package-class-writing} tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tagging

At the moment, there are 66 questions tagged with [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) and 35 questions tagged with [documentclass-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing) (6 questions feature both tags). Looking at the most upvoted [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) questions, there are quite a few that would be also useful for [documentclass-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing) (Note: I excluded questions that already feature this tag):

- [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan)
- [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)
- [How do I document my style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/how-do-i-document-my-style-files)
- [Write new package with LaTeX2e or LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35467/write-new-package-with-latex2e-or-latex3)
- [What are the established methods for filing and tracking bugs in packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10778/what-are-the-established-methods-for-filing-and-tracking-bugs-in-packages)

There are also some [documentclass-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing) questions interesting for package writers as well:

- [When or why should I use %% as opposed to %?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39490/when-or-why-should-i-use-as-opposed-to)
- [Backward compatibility for command names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15452/backward-compatibility-for-command-names)

Package writing and class writing are two related, yet somewhat different topics. The question is, are we better off by retaining two different tags and adding the respective "sibling tag" to the questions that fit both topics? Or should [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) and [documentclass-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing) be merged into a new tag called, say, [package-class-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-class-writing)?

Comment: I suggest `class-package-writing`,  since `package-class` sounds confusing, as if there was something called _package class_, as opposed to _document class_. Naming `class` first also makes sense because a document class is "hierachically" higher than a package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think there are enough differences between classes and packages that separate tags are useful.  So adding the relevant extra tags to particular questions would make more sense than merging the two tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you think that [package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-writing) and [documentclass-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing) are similar enough to be merged into a new [class-package-writing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-package-writing) tag (named as suggested by doncherry), vote up this answer. If you think two separate tags are better, vote up Alan Munn's answer.

Comment: even in 2e class should conceptually only configure base functionality and packages but not seriously adding new functionality. The distinction is certainly very sharp and there is a big gray area. But I agree with Alan that separation is useful.

Comment: on further comment: the way I look at LaTeX3 the two tasks would be totally separate (well in reality we will see a gray area there too I'm sure one day :-)

Comment: I suggest re-tag the cross-interested questions to have both tags.